# How to set Attribute in postman

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, servlets, postman

I using postman and spring boot. In spring boot i using code look like :

```
public PersistableCategory createCategory(@RequestBody PersistableCategory persistableCategory, MerchantStore store, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        MerchantStore merchantStore = (MerchantStore) httpRequest.getAttribute("MERCHANT_STORE");
        return categoryService.saveCategories(store,persistableCategory);
    }
```

get attribute from httpservletrequest. But i can't know where i set attribute with name MERCHANT_STORE  in postman. I set in body look like

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "MERCHANT_STORE": {
        "code":"1"
    }
  },
```

but it not working. How to set attribute in postman and using HttpServletRequest get it.

Comment: Not sure but I don't think you can do it without using either request params or  request body. One can also opt for path variable.

Comment: You cannot set attributes. You can set parameters or send a body.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks you. I have a question. How to pass value to "store" parameter. Because it a object and contain a lot fields : example : id, name... . I want pass value into store object. How to pass it

Answer (score -2):

1. if you have more APIs, and need to response like the request (more than one depth attribute)

```
    { 
     "attributes": {
     "MERCHANT_STORE": {
     "code":"1",
     "code2":{
     "element1":"1",
     "element2":"2"
      }}}
```

2.First, make a class for response.

```java
    public class responseData {
    private merchant_store; 
     // getter, setter, the other elements..
    }
```

3. i think that's better to make to make class for setting results.

```java
    public class result{
    private View json; // this object from spring servlet lib.
    // and make methods to parse http header(yep, in postman) and to return datas.

    }
```

4. Let's make response in controller.

```java
    public PersistableCategory createCategory(){
    MerchantStore merchantStore = (MerchantStore);
    httpRequest.getAttribute("MERCHANT_STORE");
    Object purpose = categoryService.saveCategories(store,persistableCategory); 
    Object responseData = new responseData();
    responseData.set(purpose); 
    result.set(responseData, successYn); 
    return result;
    }
```

5. Well, successYn is just String in my 
   Because i wanted to know whether it finished to access DB and set Datas. 
   if you want you can set other types.

Comment: OP asked for postman but it's not available in your solution